# list of confirmed and unconfirmed transactions of address / account

Tags: eosjs, blocks, javascript

I wanna show users a list of confirmed and unconfirmed transactions of a specific EOS address or account name, using eosjs. Similar like a Ethereum block explorer.

Any ideas or work arounds?

If there is a call to get all user transactions, I can manually check them via eos.getTransaction(id, blockNumHint)

Comment: No, you can only query all the block to get all your transactions, or subscribe specific actions in your node

Comment: Can you give me more details or a link to 'subscribe specific actions in your node'?
So wallet providers scan basically the whole blockchain to show their users their transaction history?

Answer (score 1):

To get the unconfirmed transactions, you can call

```
curl -d '{"limit":5,"json":false}' https://mainnet.eoscanada.com/v1/chain/get_scheduled_transactions
```

Replace `https://mainnet.eoscanada.com` with any active BP address including yours as long as you are running a production node with the History API Plugin.

You can also get transaction information from any EOS block explorer like https://bloks.io.